# How can i schedule a job to run always in the last day of the month with APSCHEDULER

Tags: python, apscheduler

I have a flask application that has a job that runs every minute(sends a request to an endpoint and stores some data). But now i want to make a job that runs always in the last day of every month.

I already have stored the last day of every month

```
from datetime import datetime
import calendar

now = datetime.now()
year = now.year
month = now.month
lastDay = calendar.monthrange(year, month)[1]
```

I did a job but i am not sure if this works every month or just one time.

```
def graphs():
    locale.setlocale(locale.LC_TIME, 'pt_PT.UTF-8')
    getMonth()

scheduler = BackgroundScheduler()
scheduler.add_job(func=graphs, trigger='cron', year=year, month=month, day=lastDay)
scheduler.start()
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want it to work every month, every year, you need to write:

```
from datetime import datetime
import calendar

def graphs():
    locale.setlocale(locale.LC_TIME, 'pt_PT.UTF-8')
    getMonth()

scheduler = BackgroundScheduler()
scheduler.add_job(func=graphs, trigger='cron', year='*', month='*', day='last')
scheduler.start()
```

The use of expressions like `*` and `last` to fire on every value or to fire on the last day within the month is very useful when working with a scheduler.

For more details, you can check this [documentation](https://apscheduler.readthedocs.io/en/latest/modules/triggers/cron.html)

Comment: So if i have this it Will do this job every month ONLY in The last day of The month ? He checks everyday if that day is The last day of that current month?

Comment: If you want to do the job every month only in the last day of the month, the best option is to put an expression '*' in the field month and year (so that it fires on every year and month value) and to put an expression 'last' in the field day so that it fires on the last day within the month. You don't need to store the year, the month or the lastDay. I edited my answer so that you have directly all the infos.

Comment: Oh Nice, so it triggers every month in The last day without assign any variable ?

Comment: Yes. The expression `*` can be used on any field (like year or month for example) to trigger on every value and the expression `last` can be used to trigger on the last day within the month. Don't hesitate to mark this answer as "accepted" if it helped you.

Comment: The `year` and `month` expressions here are redundant and can be left out.